# Why is the value, which is supposed to be gradually increasing as per the loop, reaching a point of no returns?

Tags: c, loops, visual-c++, gcc, for-loop

There is something I missing here because I am clueless as to why beyond the second iteration, `summation` in `sumReverse()` becomes constant but the loop continues to iterate. Relevant code:

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long cardNumber = prompt();
    unsigned short digitCount = countDigits(cardNumber);
    unsigned short biSum = sumReverse(cardNumber, digitCount, 2, 2, 2);
    unsigned short monoSum = sumReverse(cardNumber, digitCount, 1, 2, 1);
    unsigned short checkSum = biSum + monoSum;
    printf("%i\t%i\t%i\n", biSum, monoSum, checkSum);...


unsigned short sumReverse(unsigned long long cardNumber, unsigned short digitCount, unsigned short x, unsigned short step, unsigned short n)
{
    unsigned short summation = 0;
    unsigned short digit = 0;
    for (unsigned short index = x; index <= digitCount; index += step) {
        digit = singleDigit(index, cardNumber);
        digit *= n;
        if (digit > 9)
            digit = sumReverse(digit, 2, 1, 1, 1);
        printf("BEFORE: %i\t", summation);
        summation += digit;
        printf("AFTER: %i\n", summation);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return summation;
}
```

The screenshot below shows the values of `checkSum` in `sumReverse()` as written in the code above throughout its lifetime before and after each iteration.

[image: test]

I am confused and curious to know why `checkSum` reaches a point of no return.

**edit**:
Upon following nos' advice, digit becomes 0 in the iterations. Screenshot below:
[image: test]

Comment: It would help if you reduce the code to something we can actually compile and run. However, you will probably figure it out if you also print out the other variables in your loop, `digit`, `n`, `index`, the parameters to your function, and so on.

Comment: What's `singleDigit`? It's believed that your `digit` becomes `0` inside the function. Also a minimal working example that reproduces your problem would be welcomed, as @nos pointed out/

Comment: I am being tempted to just post the entire source as a link so people can just compile for themselves

Comment: @starrify, singleDigit is a function that returns a single digit located at position arg1 from the last digit in the number passed as arg2. Let me put the source for it

Comment: Check if singleDigit is returning a zero.

Comment: Yes <code>singleDigit()</code> is returning a 0 because the data size of the modulo of the long long there is larger than <code>sizeof(short)</code>. Thanks, ladies and gentlemen. I don't know what I was thinking. I actually need someone to enter an answer instead of a comment so I can mark the question answered or solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, no one is commenting I can consider this question answered courtesy of those who were commenting. LESSON: PAY ATTENTION TO DETAIL!
The problem was that in the function `singleDigit()`, the maximum capacity of a short integer was maxed and eventually equated to 0, thus the function returning 0.